# Fluent NHibernate has many mapping where child table has not primary key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, persistence

So I'm a couple of weeks into NHibernate so pleae bear with me. I am working on a legacy database with lots of weird issues.

I have a name object

```
public class Name    {    
        public Name()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
        }    
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }    
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }     
        public virtual IList<NameAddress> Addresses { get; set; }    
}
```

It has children of address

```
public class Address 
{
        public virtual string NameId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
        public virtual string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsPreferrred { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the mappings
Address has no primary key defined but it is name_id and type that make it unique. The columns you see are the table structure.

```
   Table("ADDRESS");
    CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.NameId, "NAME_ID")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Type, "ADDRESS_TYPE");
    Map(x => x.IsPreferred)
        .Column("PREF");
    Map(x => x.Line1)
        .Column("ADDRESS1");
    Map(x => x.Line2)
        .Column("ADDRESS2");
    Map(x => x.City)
        .Column("CITY");
    Map(x => x.State)
        .Column("STATE");
```

Name
            Table("NAME");

```
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Custom<XXIdentifierGenerator>(p => p.AddParam("prefix", "NAME"))
            .Column("NAME_ID");
        Map(x => x.Prefix)               
            .Column("NAME_PRE");
        Map(x => x.FirstName)
            .Column("NAME_FIRST");
        HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
            .KeyColumn("NAME_ID")
            .Table("ADDRESS")
            .LazyLoad();
```

I can create a name without any addresss and get the generated id back.

```
 repository.Save(name); // only calls session.Save and does a commit 
 Address address = new NameAddress {IsPreferred = true, Type= "Home", Line1 = "123 Main St",
                                    City = "Anytown", State = "CT", Zipcode="06512" };
 name.Addresses.Add(address);
 repository.SaveOrUpdate(name);
```

When I try to save the address I get an exception

```
     {"Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1"}
```

I am not sure if

1. My mapping is wrong
2. I don't get how to wire up a has many
3. I can't do this without a primary key
4. In this case do the addresses have to be saved on their own?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but how about adding `.Cascade.All` or similar on the `HasMany(x => x.Addresses)` mapping for `Name`?

I would imagine that NHibernate needs to know that you want new Addresses to be inserted along with a new Name.

Comment: Jay,

I just tried the cascade and it didn't work. I added the address before I saved the name as you mentioned.

If you look at the code what I am trying to do is simulate creating a new name and adding an address later. Either way I still get the error.

Comment: @Paul does it work if you set the `NAME_ID` on the `Address` explicitly?

Comment: It is trying to update the address, not insert. Here is the sql it generated. And it is not grabbing the other values.

UPDATE ADDRESS SET NAME_ID = :p0 WHERE NAME_ID = :p1 AND ADDRESS_TYPE = :p2;:p0 = 'N00052046505', :p1 = 'N00052046505', :p2 = 'Home'

Comment: @Paul Okay, I'm thinking from the error message than NHibernate is attempting to `UPDATE` the `Address` instead of `INSERT`, because the identifier is effectively assigned (and NH doesn't know whether the Address is new or not). When it attempts to update it finds no matching row instead of the 1 that it expected. I don't have much experience with assigned composite IDs, but I know that you can specify an unsaved value in the mapping, on which NHibernate can rely to identify transient from persistent instances. I think in FNH that looks something like `.UnsavedValue(null)`.

Comment: Jay, first let me thank you for all of your help. I tried the Unsavedvalue(null) and got this error - {"The 'unsaved-value' attribute is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2:unsavedValueType' - The Enumeration constraint failed."}

BTW - they fixed my dev database so it has a primary key (they left it off) on the nameid and type. What they don't have is a foreign key to the name table. I am still in the same boat.

Comment: Found this; not sure if it is helpful: http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/issues/detail?id=288 I'm wondering if it would make a difference to map this as a bidirectional association (give Address a reference to Name: `References(x => x.Name).Inverse()`); you'd have to add a Name property to the Address class to try it.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. For now I'm just managing the addresses separately. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Bummer; maybe someone else will come up with something. Good luck!